# Read int OR float from file in C

Tags: c

Let's consider a file of less than 10 numbers which can either int or float. I want to read them and add them to an array.

The issue I'm facing is that I can do that well if I have only ints for example,  but it messes things up whenever it reaches a float

in file.data

```
11
22
33.3
44
55
```

my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void usage(char * message) ;


int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    //opening the file
    FILE * flux = fopen("file.data", "r");
    if (!flux) usage("error opening the file");

    int array[10]; //array to host the data
    int i=0;
    int lu;

    while ((lu = fscanf(flux, "%i", &array[i])) !=EOF && i<10){
        printf("lu %i\n", lu );
        printf("array[%i] %i\n", i, array[i] );
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }

    return 0 ; }

void usage(char * message) { fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", message) ; exit(1) ;}
```

output :

```
lu 1
array[0] 11

lu 1
array[1] 22

lu 1
array[2] 33

lu 0
array[3] 0

lu 0
array[4] 4196464

lu 0
array[5] 0

lu 0
array[6] 4195936

lu 0
array[7] 0

lu 0
array[8] 904651696

lu 0
array[9] 32766
```

How can I use fscanf so that it doesn't get bogged down when it reaches a float?

(I can tell that it doesn't seem right to declare an array of int and to try to input some float... any way around that?)

**edit:** 
my goal is to be able to read my array and print its content with their index, for example with my data :

```
0. 11
1. 22
2. 33.3
3. 44
4. 55
```

Comment: What would you like to happen when you get to a float? Do you want to keep a rounded or `floor`d int value of the float? Do you want to keep the ints as floats? Do you want to have an array for ints and an array for floats?

Comment: The simple answer is: "you can't use `fscanf` for this". Read the line as a string and parse using other means. Use `strtol` and `strtod` with error detection.

Comment: Rethink how you view the problem. You don't have ints or floats in the file. You have strings that are separated by newlines. Read one line at a time and decide what you want to do with it based on its content.

Comment: Or, `42` can still be parsed using `%lf` into a double.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've edited my op to point out that I would later expect to read the table and print its content.

Comment: Don't read using fscanf() . Use fgets(). Now check whether string returned by fgets() contain any floating point no or not.. Implement your own atoi and atof to convert string into int and float

Comment: Thanks all for your replies and comments. It helped me understand what I was trying to achieve and gave me good leads to keep going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you only need integers? If so you can read float and convert them into integers before putting them in the array:

```
float tmp;
while ((lu = fscanf(flux, "%f", &tmp)) !=EOF && i<10){
    array[i] = (int)tmp; //you could use some rounding here
    printf("lu %i\n", lu );
    printf("array[%i] %i\n", i, array[i] );
    printf("\n");
    i++;
}
```